# How to pull a changing class name with Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm testing my web scraping skills with Python and Selenium and I found an button with a changing "id" "ember" and the numbers change everytime.  Everything else is the same as all buttons.  The only thing that's unqiue is

```html
<button aria-label="View only People results" id="ember697" class="search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view" type="button"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    People
</span></button>

I've tried all the methods so far (i.e., id, CSS_selector, xpath, etc.).
[![Linked In button][1]][1]
```

Here's the error I keep getting no matter what I select.

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Comment: So, do you want to search by `aria-label`, `class`, or something else?

Comment: What is the issue, then?

Comment: @AyushGarg, yes please.  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @AMC, I edited the original post.  I get a no such element exception error.

Comment: @BrandonJacobson Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since you want to search through `aria-label`, you can use an `XPATH`:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='View only People results']")
```

**EDIT:** You could also use a css selector like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[aria-label='View only People results'']")
```

Comment: The xpath suggestion worked.  When I hit inspect, then copy xpath, it doesn't give me the syntax you provided.  I guess I have to learn more about Selenium's syntax.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
option1 - i am assuming ember will be there and only numbers are changing

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'ember')]")
```

option 2-

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'ember')")
```

option 3-

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'search-vertical-filter__filter-item-button')")
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: So, there are multiple buttons with the ember id.  I didn't know you can do "starts-with" though.  Thank you so much.  I guess I still have more to learn about the Selenium syntax.